# Do I need an extra wifi router to setup mesh wifi system?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I am trying to set up a mesh wifi system (eero pro, for example) at home.

From what I found so far, it seems that I will need at least a cable modem (say, netgear cm1100). However, I am not sure if I still need an extra wifi router (such as netgear AC2300), or just cable modem and the mesh wifi?

I am not sure what devices I need to setup a mesh wifi. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For mesh wifi, you only need a mesh wifi system. The modem is so you connect internet to it. But if you want to create a mesh wifi setup to only have a local network between devices without internet, you don't need a modem. There are mesh wifi systems that have a modem part incorporated if I'm not mistaken, so maybe you saw that?

Comment: Obviously I need internet, so looks like I would have to need a cable modem?

Comment: 2 or more routers are needed to set up a mesh network, Identical routers are best. Most people buy 2 or more identical routers and put on custom firmware for best results, no all routers can run custom firmware, do your research before purchase. Or buy a preconfigured mesh kit>>>>https://www.pcmag.com/picks/the-best-wi-fi-mesh-network-systems

Comment: "so looks like I would have to need a cable modem?' Yes you need internet service to start.

Comment: @Moab: so when you say "two or more routers are needed ......." do you mean mesh wifi router? or like a regular (non mesh wifi) router?

Comment: @Moab there are actually complete mesh network systems. You have one base station and it comes with additional hubs that you place around the place wirelessly.

Comment: That is why I posted the link @LPChip

Comment: @LPChip I would accept either of your answers if you post it as an answer. Very appreciate your help!

Comment: @Moab I would accept either of your answers if you post it as an answer. Very appreciate your help!

Comment: Done. :) Enjoy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mesh wifi, you only need a mesh wifi system. The modem is so you connect internet to it. But if you want to create a mesh wifi setup to only have a local network between devices without internet, you don't need a modem. There are mesh wifi systems that have a modem part incorporated if I'm not mistaken, so maybe you saw that?

There are actually complete mesh network systems. You have one base station and it comes with additional hubs that you place around the place wirelessly.

See also: https://www.pcmag.com/picks/the-best-wi-fi-mesh-network-systems

Alternatively, you can create a mesh network by configuring 2 routers that support it natively or through custom firmware.